# Show that there exists a total derivative and determine the partial derivates $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> For both $u:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\upsilon: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ the total derivative exist. The function $f$ is defined as: 
> $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y):=u(x,y,v(x,y))$ 
> (i) Show that $f$ is totally differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2$ 
> (ii) Determine the partial derivates $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ (by paying attention to the partial derivates of $u$ and $v$)

My ideas:

(i) First the definition:

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is totally differentiable in $x_0$ if there exists a linear function $A:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ with:
$f(x)-f(x_0)=A(x-x_0)+r(x-x_0)$

Unfortunately I'm not really sure how to proceed from the definition.

(ii)

First we determine the partial derivates of $v(x,y)$ and for that we define $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$:

$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}$

To determine the partial derivates of the whole function:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}$

and

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}$

So I'm using the chain rule.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: The composition of differentiable functions is differentiable... The differentiability of $u,v$ can be used to justify (i).